# comparing values from drop down menus from form using javascript

Tags: javascript

On my form I have used javascript to validate user input, however I would like to compare the values of two different drop down menus to check they aren't the same. 
Two drop down menus "Pick up location" and "Destination" contain exactly the same town names available for each, so the user can easily select the same town for both, which I don't want.
Any ideas how to achieve this if it's possible? Thanks

code:

```
function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
var reason = "";

reason += validatepickuplocation(theForm.pickuplocation);

if (reason != "") {
alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
return false;
}

return true;
}

function validatePickuplocation(fld) {
var pickuplocation = document.getElementById("pickuplocation");
var destination = document.getElementById("destination");

if (pickuplocation.options[pickuplocation.selectedIndex].value ==   destination.options[destination.selectedIndex].value) {
fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
error = "Make sure 'Pick up location' and 'Destination' are not the same locations.\n"
} else {
fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;
}
```

html:

```
<tr>
<td><label for="pickuplocation">Pick up location:</label></td>
<td><select name="pickuplocation" size="1">
<OPTIONS>
</select></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="destination">Pick up location:</label></td>
<td><select name="destination" size="1">
<OPTIONS>
</select></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just set each dropdown box value as a separate variable and compare them:

```
var a = document.getElementById("dropDownA");
var b = document.getElementById("dropDownB");

if (a.options[a.selectedIndex].value == b.options[b.selectedIndex].value) {
    // Do Some stuff
} else {
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: you want the second field to disable/disappear the first town selected? or just block the form submit? if the form submit, then david hamp solution should work.

Comment: to stop the form being submitted yes, for some reason doesn't want to work for me

Comment: i've placed the code on the page, sorry im quite new to javascript

Comment: Ah, you don't have an id set for your select boxes.  getElementById won't select them due to that.  I would just ad an id attribute on those and it should work.